# SQL Server view definition

Tags: sql, view, sql-server-express

How can I see the SQL script that was used to create view?  I'm using MS SQL Server Management Studio Express 2008.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In object explorer (left hand pane):
- Right click the view
- Script View As ->
- CREATE TO ->
- New Query Editor Window

That will open a new query window with the create script for the view.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the View -> Modify

EDIT: Much better

Right click on the View -> Script View As -> Create TO

There you can export the create script to a destination of your choice